# Nginx route all rest of the Path

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, proxy, routes, reverse-proxy

please  let us know if its possible on Nginx/AWS-ALB

Need to server static Home page on domain
Ex: example.com will route to home page

**all rest of the request has to forward to application-server/tomcat**

**example.com/abc ,example.com/xyz etc has to route to application-server/tomcat**

we don't have any common routing path for application
have multiple routes
how to configure to route all rest of the path to application except home path

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=` modifier to define an exact match for the root path:

```
location = / {
  # root path
}
location / {
  # everything else
}
```

See [`ngx_http_core_module` docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).